# Hiding TabNavigator when the keyboard appears

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I use TabNavigator in my react native application from react-navigation,
this is my tabNavigator :

```
TabNavigator({      
  Newsstand: { screen: Newsstand }
}, {
  tabBarComponent: NavigationComponent,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    bottomNavigationOptions: {
      labelColor: 'white',
      rippleColor: 'white',
      tabs: {
        Newsstand: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#2F4F4F',          
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Now the problem is that I want it to not appear in top of the keyboard when Im typing in my app. How can I do that ?

I want to be able to add it in a scroll view so It won't jump in top of the keyboard but stay fixed in bottom behind it

Answer (score 0):

As [their docs](https://github.com/expo/react-native-tab-navigator) say you can hide it with:

```
let tabBarHeight = 0;
 <TabNavigator
   tabBarStyle={{ height: tabBarHeight, overflow: 'hidden' }}
   sceneStyle={{ paddingBottom: tabBarHeight }}
 />
```

have you tried

```
this.state = {
  tabHeight: 50,
  ...
  }
```

and in your TabNavigator:

```
...height: this.state.tabHeight, ...
```

then setting state with

```
this.setState({tabHeight: 0});
```

Comment: It didn't work, I want to be able to add it in a scroll view so It won't jump in top of the keyboard but stay fixed in bottom behind it

Comment: the link in your answer is to a different package. OP is talking about react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
"android":{"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"}
```

in your app.json

or

```
android:softwareKeyboardLayoutMode="pan",
```

in your manifest